# Error installing GMP on cygwin "configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details"

Tags: cygwin, gmp

I got the following error in configuring GMP while building a bare metal GNU cross toolchain for Xtensa on cygwin

configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details

The build was performed using a crosstool-NG downloaded from the site http://wiki.linux-xtensa.org/index.php/Crosstool-NG using the git clone git clone https://github.com/foss-xtensa/crosstool-NG.git

This downloads GMP-5.1.1 while downloading GCC and related packages.

1. Build environment - cygwin
2. The GMP version number - GMP-5.1.1
3. Output of gcc -v

   ```
   $ gcc -v
   Using built-in specs.
   COLLECT_GCC=gcc
   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/lto-wrapper.exe
   Target: i686-pc-cygwin
   Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.9.3-1.i686/src/gcc-   4.9.3/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.9.3-1.i686/src/gcc-4.9.3 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id
   Thread model: posix
   gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC)
   ```
4. The output from running ‘uname -a’.

   ```
   $ uname -a
   CYGWIN_NT-6.1 si-hnhari 2.1.0(0.287/5/3) 2015-07-14 21:26 i686 Cygwin
   ```

The output of config.log and build.log is attached.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks and Regards,
Hari

Comment: your CFLAGS are not proper

Comment: Why try an old version? Where are the log files attached?

Comment: I tried with the latest 6.0.0a. same problem. The cygwin gcc version is gcc 4.9.3. I cannot upload files at work. Any idea which version of gcc should I use for building on cygwin ?

Answer (score 0):

We just got support in crosstool-ng upstream:

https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/pull/253

It's available now in git, master branch, or in the upcoming release on Friday November 20th: 1.22.0

Currently, there is only xtensa support for gcc-5.2.0. I'm not sure if Max plans to backport it to 4.9.x.